# How this GUI control (usually used for logging) is called? What is wxpython alternative?

Tags: wxpython, progress

please look at his control:

[image]

Is this multiline text control or is there something more advanced? And how they are populated? Are they populated by concatenating a new string to the previous string? Please provide some insight into how to make fast progress controls of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That screen cap looks like a simple RichEdit or Scintilla control. That doesn't really matter for your OP however. Those controls are simply more advanced text editors that support formatting beyond your standard text boxes with such fanciness as colors and different fonts etc. and there are many like them.

For implementing something similar with Python you could use the [wxStyledTextControl](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Scintilla) which wraps the Scintilla control to provide the text formatting.

Also look [here](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/index.html) and [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SciTe) for further wxStyledTextControl info and links.